# How to get the count of each category using group by?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 framework. I want to count the number of records of each category.
Here i have two tables

```
eve_appointment_icons ->having columns- appointment_icon_id,appointment_icon_type_name
eve_appointments ->having columns- id, appointment_icon_id
```

I have fetch this data using this query:-

```
$this->EveAppointment->query("SELECT
                    a.appointment_type
                    d.appointment_icon_id,
                    a.appointment_icon_id , 
                    d.appointment_icon_type_name,   
                FROM  eve_appointments a,
                    eve_appointment_icons d
                WHERE  a.appointment_type =1
                AND d.appointment_icon_id = a.appointment_icon_id

            UNION
                SELECT 
                    a.appointment_type
                    d.appointment_icon_id,
                    a.appointment_icon_id , 
                    d.appointment_icon_type_name,   

                FROM  eve_appointments a,
                    eve_appointment_icons d
                WHERE  a.appointment_type =2
                    AND d.appointment_icon_id = a.appointment_icon_id
            UNION
                SELECT 
                    a.appointment_type
                    d.appointment_icon_id,
                    a.appointment_icon_id , 
                    d.appointment_icon_type_name, 
                FROM  eve_appointments a,
                    eve_appointment_icons d
                WHERE a.appointment_type =3
                    AND d.appointment_icon_id = a.appointment_icon_id");
```

Here when I print this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 1
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Yoga
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 1
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Yoga
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 2
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Visit
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 3
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Physio Therapy
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 4
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Diagnostic
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 4
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Diagnostic
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [appointment_icon_id] => 4
        [appointment_icon_type_name] => Diagnostic
    )
)
```

Now you can see the Yoga having `appointment_icon_id` is `1`, visit having `appointment_icon_id` `2` and vice versa for others.
I want count of all these categories.
Like:

```
appointment_icon_type_name    count
 Yoga                           2
 Visit                          1
 Physio Therapy                 1
 Diagnostic                     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
select d.appointment_icon_type_name, count(*)   
FROM  eve_appointments a,
eve_appointment_icons d
WHERE d.appointment_icon_id = a.appointment_icon_id
group by d.appointment_icon_type_name
```